# Voximplant: Not receiving message from "sendMessage" method

Tags: voximplant

I am trying to use Call.sendMessage method to send info from VoxEngine to WebSDK during the call.

VoxEngine scenario:

```
call.sendMessage("Test message");
```

Browser js:

```
voxAPI.addEventListener(VoxImplant.Events.MessageReceived, onMessageReceived);
function onMessageReceived(e){
    console.log("onMessageReceived");
    console.log(e.text);
}
```

VoxEngine log shows that everything is ok (Executing JS command: SendMessage), but browsers don't receive it .
Firefox shows warning "Invalid URI. Load of media resource  failed.". Chrome shows nothing.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try add async first on your function onMessageReceived like this :

```
async function onMessageReceived(e){
    console.log("onMessageReceived");
    console.log(e.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that issue is related to the way you subscribe to the **MessageReceived** event.
This is a CallEvent: https://voximplant.com/docs/references/websdk/voximplant/callevents#messagereceived
So, you need to change your code to something like:

```
call.on(VoxImplant.CallEvents.MessageReceived, <your_handler>);
```